# Access iOS source files under pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, assets

What is the best approach to access project source files (.h/.m or Assets.xcassets) under podfile. I'm using a library and want to access my source files in my project. I don't want to hard code anything because I'm using some globally defined parameters.
- I guess podspec is one option (not sure), but I don't want to call `pod update` each time I made a change in podfile.
See attached image:

[image]

Comment: I dont think, you can access it in Pods!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using those classes in a single project, then there is no advantage in putting them in a separate pod. If they are used in multiple projects and are rarely modified, then you can consider creating a [private Pod](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html). In that case, however, you will need to call `pod update` every time you release a new build to your private pod.

Comment: It's only one pod but there is no other way I guess. If there was I really would like to know. 
If the only way is creating my own pod then I would do so.Because I will use those files to create different apps and they have color codes, service urls and so on. So instead hardcoding everything, it's more convenient to use the .h files.

Comment: @efdalustaoglu Then it seems like creating your own private pod is the best option here. We have an internal pod just like yours in our company and every domain-independent and utility class is in in there, and you just don't need to release new builds as often after a while, so it's not really a burden to `pod update` every once in a while.